# keep unread inbox messages highlighted, keep unread notification count in top bar icon

Tags: feature-request, notifications, top-bar, global-inbox

I dread clicking on the inbox icon because clicking it means that all messages are no longer "unread" and the notification number (usually color red) will go away. It means we must wait until we am ready and expect to have the time to go over all notifications (which may not be the case, especially if we are interrupted to go do something else).

Sometimes, we just don't want to look at all new messages at once, and we want to keep them unread so we know what we need to get back to later.

The useful highlight on each message fades away when we click on the inbox icon. After navigating, it is no longer possible to tell which topics we have already visited because the highlights are gone.

It would be great if inbox items were left unread (and still highlighted) until clicked on, and the top bar numerical indicator left with a number of how many unread are left, so that we have a clear way of knowing which items we need to get back to instead of having to check all of them to regain context of what we're doing.

The following is what I see. I had many unread items, but I can not tell which ones I already visited and which ones I still have to read, which makes things more difficult. All of the following items except for two are unread. Can you tell which ones are unread?

[image]